# bash make quote not explained escaping

Tags: bash, escaping, quote

I want to make bash quote `"` not explained

more over I want to exec following command line in bash

```
gnuplot -e "filename='data.dat'" plot.gnuplot
```

And I try to wrapping that in bash script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

gnuplot -e "filename=\'${1}\'" plot.gnuplot
```

and exec the aboving bashscript like this

```
bash -x plot.sh data.dat
```

but it shows this:

```
 + gnuplot -e 'filename=\'\''data.dat\'\''' plot.gnuplot

filename=\'data.dat\'
         ^
line 0: invalid character \
```

How to do that?

Comment: Why are you using python encoding in a bash script?

Comment: @l'L'l to tell vim the default encoding

Comment: I see; maybe try setting your filename variable before the command (eg. `filename="'${1}'"` then `gnuplot -e "$filename" plot.gnuplot`...

Comment: if I understand you right, this will not work since variable wrapped by `''` will not be explained by bash so `'${1}'` will be kept literally

Comment: How about `path="filename='${1}'"` then `gnuplot -e "$path" plot.gnuplot`

Comment: Sorry, it works!, please make this a answer so I can accept that :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the variable ahead of the command:

```
path="filename='${1}'"
gnuplot -e "$path" plot.gnuplot
```

If quotes need to be around the variable:

```
path="\"filename='${1}'\""
gnuplot -e "$path" plot.gnuplot
```

Setting the variable as one command:

```
gnuplot -e "\"filename='${1}'\"" plot.gnuplot
```